# Is there an Internet Explorer webdriver configuration for ignoring security certificates on serenity?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

For context, I use a `serenity.properties` file for my webdriver configurations. 
I am using serenity 2/cucumber 4/java.

I wanted to use something similar to how Chrome driver works with serenity properties.. Something like:

```
chrome.capabilities.acceptInsecureCerts = true
```

Which allows me to bypass that the security certificate error for Chrome Driver.

But I couldn't find something similar to this configuration for the serenity IE driver.

**My question is**: is there a way to do this via `serenity.properties` configurations similarly for IE driver, rather then having to declare and pass something like this?

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

[source](https://www.guru99.com/ssl-certificate-error-handling-selenium.html)

Things I've tried while running on my selenium grid:

```
iexplorer.capabilities.acceptInsecureCerts = true
iexplorer.capabilities.acceptSslCerts = true
iexplorer.capabilities.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains = true
iexplorer.capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled = true
```

Should `iexplorer.capabilities` even work?

*Example of security certificate error on IE:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the selenium IE webdriver document and github forum, and search lots of resources about how to handle the SSL Certificate in Selenium IE WebDriver. It seems that we could only set the ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS property via the [DesiredCapabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) method, and use the following code for IE Webdriver:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```